# dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp' command is not returning the values

Tags: android, windows

I have connected a real device and opened the app on it.however if i type the below command in cmd

> dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'

i get the below error`'dumpsys' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Although i was able to get the main-activity and package-activity using same command before for same app.please help me figure out what i might have entered wrong  or any other changes needs to be done

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can add the device model and the firmware version you are on so that people know what they need to answer and how to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 3):

dumpsys is a shell command. You can run it from the command line as follows:

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus | mFocusedApp'
```

If you have multiple devices connected, first get their IDs by executing:

```
adb devices
```

Then, replace `<your-device-id>` with the relevant device ID:

```
adb -s <your-device-id> shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus | mFocusedApp'
```